# display filename at the bottom of thumbnail

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am using dropzone to upload image in Laravel.

Is there any way to display the image name at the bottom of the thumbnail?

I know that the image name will be shown when hovering to the thumbnail but i wish to show the filename at the bottom of the thumbnail without hovering to the thumbnail.

The codes are as below.

my dropzone js in my upload page.

```
Dropzone.options.imageUpload = {
  paramName: "image", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 30, // MB
  uploadMultiple: true,
  clickable: true,
  maxThumbnailFilesize: 30,
  parallelUploads: 1,
  maxFiles: 10,
  dictMaxFilesExceeded: "This image is exceeded the limit upload",
  init: function() {
    this.on("queuecomplete", function(file) { $("#buttons").show(); });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
      done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  } 
};
```

my upload controller

```
 $User = Auth::user()->id;
    $category = Category::active()->first();
    $sizeHeight = Size::orderBy('height', 'ASC')->where('status', 0)->first();
    $sizeWidth = Size::orderBy('width', 'ASC')->where('status', 0)->first();
    $files = $request->file('image');

    if( !empty( $files ) ):
        $urls = array();
        foreach( $files as $val => $file ):
            $now = Carbon::now();
            $time = str_replace(':', '-', $now);
            //$number = $val + 1;

            echo $sizeHeight;
            echo $sizeWidth;
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //get image size
            $filepath = $file->getRealPath();
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filepath);
            //if wrong orientation then

            if($width >= $sizeWidth->width || $height >= $sizeHeight->height)
            {
                // Ryan 22 October 2016 (Saturday) move save photo to top 
                $photo = new photo;
                $photo->user_id = $User;
                $photo->photoName = $time . $filename;
                $photo->category_id = $category->id;
                $photo->subcategory_id = "1";
                $photo->name = null;
                $photo->keyword = null;
                $photo->status = "2";
                $photo->save();

             }
    endif;
```

This is my current result when I am hovering the thumbnail

[image]

And I wanted it to be something like this without hovering.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Please add some code...

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: @MinalChauhan I have updated my code

Comment: @ManishPatel I have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add text to the picture, you can use [Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) package for Laravel. [`text()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/text) method will help you with that.

> Write a text string to the current image at an optional x,y basepoint position. You can define more details like font-size, font-file and alignment via a callback as the fourth parameter.

If you just want to show some text over an image without editing the file, you can [use CSS](https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) for that.

Comment: I dont want to add text to my picture. I just want to show my filename at the bottom of my dropzone thumbnail